# Vagrant box timeout value while waiting for machine to boot

Tags: linux, windows, laravel, virtualbox, homestead

In windows i added homestead and try to run

```
vagrant up
```

It executed and shows me the following error

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead-7: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> homestead-7: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> homestead-7: A newer version of the box 'laravel/homestead' is available! Yo                                                                                                                u currently
==> homestead-7: have version '3.0.0'. The latest is version '3.1.0'. Run
==> homestead-7: `vagrant box update` to update.
==> homestead-7: Setting the name of the VM: homestead-7
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> homestead-7: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    homestead-7: Adapter 1: nat
    homestead-7: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> homestead-7: Forwarding ports...
    homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> homestead-7: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> homestead-7: Booting VM...
==> homestead-7: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    homestead-7: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    homestead-7: SSH username: vagrant
    homestead-7: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

I tried many things but it shows me the same error again and again. I do know what to do.Could any one help me to solve this

Comment: Did you try changing `config.vm.boot_timeout` in your VagrantFile?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the VM in your BIOS? If it's the 1st time you are doing it, you need to enable it, it's locked by default.